# Bash 101, $HOME/ivy/bin/node, not showing in the "require.paths" of node's environment

Tags: node.js, bash, ivy

I'm trying to complete the following tutorial:

http://howtonode.org/deploying-node-with-spark

I've installed ivy and if I go `cd $HOME/ivy/bin`, then type in `node`, I'll get the node environment. However, after I add this to `.profile`:

> PATH="$HOME/ivy/bin:$PATH"

I'll exit my session, log back in and here's what `require.paths` shows:

```
> require.paths
[ '/home/myusername/.node_modules',
  '/home/myusername/.node_libraries',
  '/usr/local/lib/node' ]
```

It is not picking up the `'/home/myusername/ivy/lib/node'` ... what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require.paths` has been changed since July (when the article was published).

```
var modulePaths = [path.join(process.execPath, '..', '..', 'lib', 'node')];

if (process.env['HOME']) {
  modulePaths.unshift(path.join(process.env['HOME'], '.node_libraries'));
  modulePaths.unshift(path.join(process.env['HOME'], '.node_modules'));
}

if (process.env['NODE_PATH']) {
  modulePaths = process.env['NODE_PATH'].split(':').concat(modulePaths);
}
```

See: https://github.com/ry/node/blob/master/src/node.js#L133

You now need to define `NODE_PATH` and add the path(s) there:

```
# add ~/foo and ~/bla to the require.paths
export NODE_PATH=$HOME/foo:$HOME/bla
```

Results in:

```
> require.paths
[ '/home/ivo/foo',
  '/home/ivo/bla',
  '/home/ivo/.node_modules',
  '/home/ivo/.node_libraries',
  '/home/ivo/.local/lib/node' ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Should it maybe be in your `.bash_profile` file or `.bashrc` file instead?  Sounds to me like your `.profile` file is not being sourced.

Comment: I added the path to those files as well, no difference.

Comment: what happens when you use `env` at your terminal before invoking node?

Comment: It correctly shows up when I run env: PATH=/home/myusername/ivy/bin

Comment: One final question, since I don't actually know a whole lot about node itself, are you exporting PATH after you change it?  If you don't, then the change won't reflect itself in any child processes.

Comment: If that doesn't fix it, then I defer to someone who knows more about node than I.